# Snapping effect / Focus on a Container for a ListView.builder scrolling vertically

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I currently have a ListView.builder of containers that expand once I tap it. However, I'd like the containers to center in on the expanded container that was tapped.

[List of items mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaNJY.png)

[Expanded Container mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1SAt.png)

Currently, if I tap on No.2 from the Expanded Container mockup picture, the container will expand but it won't snap/focus on that container. I'd like to find a way to make this possible.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you want the Expanded Tile to be in the center, and as long as the Tile is expanded, the List should be unresponsive?

Comment: No, to clarify, I don't currently have any Expanded containers. I have containers that expand onTap to show more information but once those containers expand I want the list to scroll and center in that container. Sorry for the confusion.